# Form Element with Variable

Tags: vba, excel

If I want to use a variable within the name of a variable, how would I do that?  Im a bit rusty and can't remember or find the correct syntax to do this.

Ex:

```
For x = 1 To 6
    txtBoard [x].Caption = rst(0)
    If Not rst(0) = "" Then
        boardPresent(x) = True
    End If
    txtBoardSer [x].Caption = rst(1)
    rst.MoveNext
Next
```

Comment: what kind of object are `txtBoard` and `txtBoardSer`?

Comment: They are 'Label' objects.

Comment: how many of them and how are they called?

Comment: There is 6.  They are called txtBoard1, txtBoard2, etc...

Comment: Is this VBA? What is MoveNext?

Comment: in vba `txtBoard [x]` is wrong use `txtBoard (x)`

Comment: I know it's wrong, thats why Im asking!  :)

Comment: @SJR MoveNext is used for cycling through an array recordset when querying an SQL table.

Comment: @Addohm - ok, thanks. Not familiar with that. If these are on a userform you could try `Me.Controls("txtBoard" & x)`.

Comment: @cyboashu That doesnt work.

Comment: @SJR That worked, thanks so much.   `Me.Controls("txtBoard" & x).Caption = rst(0)`

Answer (score 1):

use `Controls` collection of your userform object to grab controls by their name

```
    With Me '<--| reference your userform
        For x = 1 To 6
            .Controls("txtBoard" & x).Caption = rst(0)
            If Not rst(0) = "" Then
                boardPresent(x) = True
            End If
            .Controls("txtBoardSer" & x).Caption = rst(1)
            rst.MoveNext
        Next
    End With
```